# onClick not working on my React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have composite components. The parent component should be able to pass props to child components when clicked.

When I add the `onClick` handler to the search component of my header, there are no messages printed to the console.

Parent component header

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import Search from "./search"

const Container = styled.header``
const Wrapper = styled.div``

function Header () {
  function toggleSearch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Search')
  }

  return ( 
    <Container>
      <Wrapper>
        <Search onClick={toggleSearch} />
      </Wrapper>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Header
```

and the child component search

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const Container = styled.span``
const Icon = styled(FontAwesomeIcon)

const Search = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Icon icon={faSearch} />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Search
```

- When I add a button to the Header, the click event fires.
- When I change the Search container to a button instead of a span then the button can be clicked but the message is not written to the console.

How do I get my click event to fire?

---

I am using

```
"react": "^16.9.0"
"styled-components": "^4.3.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Search` is a component, the `onClick` event handler has to be passed onto the element inside it. `onClick` is as any other prop on a component and has no default meaning.

```
const Search = ({onClick}) => {
  return (
    <Container onClick={onClick}>
      <Icon icon={faSearch} />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: I saw Dacre's answer first. Yours is also valuable to me because you destructure props which is great. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the custom `Search` component does not implement an `onClick` callback prop. Extending `Search` with the following should resolve the issue:

```
/* Add props argument */
const Search = (props) => {
  return (
    {/* Add onClick prop to span, and pass through supplied onClick prop */}
    <Container onClick={props.onClick}>
      <Icon icon={faSearch} />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should add that onClick props in Search component. You are not utilising that props. If you want on click on let say on icon element then you should do something like this.

```
const Search = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Icon icon={faSearch} onClick={props.onClick} />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

If you want it to add on Container element then you should do like this.

```
const Search = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container onClick={props.onClick}>
      <Icon icon={faSearch} />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is basically the same as the previous ones but I do appreciate that you shared your insights with me.